# Laravel 5.2 - high page's first time loading time - performance tester?

Tags: php, performance, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I've created a website in laravel 5.2 and I've put it online.
I've noticed that when I go to the website for the first time after some hours (I can't say how much hours), it takes up to 12 seconds to fully load the page, while it normally takes 3.5 seconds for the following attempts.

I can say that it's not a matter of browser's cache, cause I've tested it by deleting it evertime and got the same result.
I'm not using (intentionally at least) any kind of caching system in my laravel project.
I've tested the website with YSlow and Pagespeed, followed their suggestions, and I've got a very good rank, even though a high TTFB.
MySQL queries are not that high in number (2 if I remember correctly).

Questions:

- Is there in Laravel 5.2 some kind of default cache system that I don't know?
- Is there a way or a tool to know in detail what takes so much time (even server-side)? Cause tools like chrome devtools can't obviously go so deep into a server-side process.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [cache system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache) in Laravel. You should use `production` environment, so Laravel will cache everything (configuration, routes etc).

Also, try to run `php artisan optimize`, this should also speed up an app.

Comment: php artisan optimize before project deployment seems to have fixed the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
php artisan cache:clear
```